# how to submit form data on google spreadsheet using core php

Tags: php

i have seen many examples on Google but all related to zendframe work but I want it in core php only. I am giving some links below on those links explained how to use but its also in zendframe work.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-googledata1/index.html?ca=drs-

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-googledata2/index.html?ca=drs-

Please gives response ASAP

Thanks in advance.